# select query in three tables with join

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I have three tables in access 2010 (room_info, student_info, commodity_info)

1- room_info

```
room_id - autonumber - primary key
room_no - number
floor_no - text 
part_type - text
year_reserved - text
```

2- student_info

```
student_id - autonumber - primary key
student_name - text
college - text
dept - text
stage - text
card_id - number
mobile_No - number
room_id - number - foreign key
```

3- commodity_info

```
commodity_id - autonumber - primary key
chair - number
desk - number ..............
room_id - number - foreign key
```

I want to make a select query to select data from these three tables in c#?

Comment: Then make one.  What is your question?

Comment: It's very odd combination i.e **`C# with MS-Access`**

Answer (score 1):

**[INNER JOIN in MS-ACCESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208854%28v=office.12%29.aspx)**

I won't provide you the complete `C# code` as that would be like spoon feeding.

```
select *
from ((room_info
inner join student_info on room_info.room_id =student_info.room_id)
inner join commodity_info on room_info.room_id =commodity_info.room_id)
```

Comment: select *
from ((room_info
inner join student_info on room_info.room_id =student_info.room_id)
inner join commodity_info on room_info.room_id =commodity_info.room_id)

Comment: thank you for answer ... but i don't want to select all fields an the tables i want to select some fields ... i want query to select some fields in every three table?

Comment: select a.field, b.field, c.field from ((tablea a inner join tableb b on a.field = b.field) inner join tablec c on b.field = c.field)

Comment: mr Geek thank you for your answer ... and i need a where clause with this query can i write the where clause in the end of query?

Comment: i gives me error said 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression'?

Comment: What is the actual error, and how are you using the Query in C#. Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: iam using query like this ....................................select [room_info].room_number,[room_info].floor_no,[student_info].student_name,[student_info].college,[commodity_info].sysam,[commodity_info].doshak from ((room_info inner join student_info on room_info.room_id =student_info.room_id) inner join commodity_info on room_info.room_id =commodity_info.room_id)......?